# Java-How do I compare generic types?

Tags: java, oop, generics

Here's the code for a generic binary search tree. Now, it runs and compiles perfectly, but with one problem that I only noticed now, after I have finished this class. The problem is that the insert method uses compareTo()(when it comes to comparing the nodes' elements) to decide where to place the next node in the tree according to its' value. And for instance for an input of:

> 1, 112, 2

instead of getting this tree:

```
 1  
  \   
    2    
     \    
     112
```

What I end up getting is:

```
       1
         \
          2
         / 
        112
```

Because probably the comparison is done in a lexicographically way and so it see 2 > 112.

Here's the code for the Tree class:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.lang.*;

public class Tree<T extends Comparable<T>>
    { private Node<T> root = null;
    static String S="";

    public Tree()
        {File file=new File("date.in.txt");

            try 
            { Scanner input = new Scanner( file );
            while(input.hasNext())
                 insert((T)input.next());} 

            catch (FileNotFoundException ex) 
                { System.out.printf("ERROR: %s!\n", ex); } }


    public void show(){ printLevelOrder(maxDepth()); }

    public void printLevelOrder(int depth) 
        { for (int i = 1; i <= depth; i++) 
            { System.out.print("Level " + (i-1) + ": ");
            String levelNodes = printLevel(root, i);
            System.out.print(levelNodes + "\n"); } }

    public String printLevel(Node<T> t, int level) 
        { if (t == null) 
            return "";
        if (level == 1) 
            return t.element + " ";
         else if (level > 1) 
            { String leftStr = printLevel(t.left, level - 1);
            String rightStr = printLevel(t.right, level - 1);
            return leftStr + rightStr; }
        else 
          return ""; }


    int maxDepth(){ return maxDepth2(root); }

    int maxDepth2(Node<T> node) 
        { if (node == null) 
            return (0);
         else 
            { int leftDepth = maxDepth2(node.left);
            int rightDepth = maxDepth2(node.right);

            if (leftDepth > rightDepth )
                return (leftDepth + 1);
            else
                return (rightDepth + 1); } }


    public String toString(){ return this.InOrder(); }


    public String InOrder(){ inOrder2(root); return S; }

    public void inOrder2(Node<T> root) 
        { if(root !=  null)   
            { inOrder2(root.left);    
            S=S+root.element+" ";  
            inOrder2(root.right); } }


    public boolean insert(T element)  // I N S E R T    M E T H O D
        { if (isEmpty()) 
            { root = new Node<T>(element);
            return true; }

         Node<T> current = root; 
         Node<T> parent;         

         do 
            { parent = current;

             if (element.compareTo(current.element)<0) 
                 current = current.left; 
              else if (element.compareTo(current.element)>0) 
                 current = current.right; 
              else 
                 return false; } 
             while (current != null);

         Node<T> node = new Node<T>(element);


             if ( element.compareTo(parent.element)>0  ) 
                 parent.right = node;
          else 
             parent.left = node;

         return true; } 


    public boolean isEmpty() { return root == null; }


    private static class Node<T extends Comparable<T>>   
        { Node<T> left  = null;
        Node<T> right = null;
        final T element;

        Node(T element) { this.element = element; } } }
```

And here's the main:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class Main 
    {public static void main(String[]args)
        {Tree <Double> T=new Tree<>(); } }
```

Now I did a little bit of research and asked here and there, and I got wind of something called comparator but I haven't quite used one before and I'm not sure how to implement it. Now if you got any solution to how to fix this, or what to add/do, I'm all eyes and ears homies.

Comment: A lexicographic comparison would put 1 < 112, so that's not what's going on (or not all of what's going on).

Comment: Also, if T is Integer, compareTo won't be a lexicographic comparison, and if T is String, you need to stop storing integers as strings and make T Integer. Comparators are almost certainly not the right solution.

Comment: @user2357112 Now I realized I had my drawing done wrong. I re-did them, that's what it actually turns out to be. 112<2 which I guess has to do with lexicographic order.

Comment: @user2357112 So you seem like a guy who knows his stuff, got any ideas?

Comment: Please post a complete examle, with main method http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: What is the type of the inputs?  T is comparable, compareTo defines the `natural ordering`.  What exactly the natural ordering depends on what type you are dealing with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your line `insert((T)input.next());` doesn't make sense - `input.next()` is a `String`, but you're casting it to a `T` even though `T` isn't associated with a real type at this point. When constructing a `Tree` a caller could, for instance, say `new Tree<Integer>` making that line, in essence, `insert((Integer)input.next());`, which is broken.

If your goal is for `Tree` to always contain `String`s, just remove the generic `T` type from `Tree` and just use `String`. If you actually want to support arbitrary types you need to move the file-reading behavior out of the `Tree` constructor (e.g. into a static method that returns a `Tree<String>`).

For example:

```
public static Tree<String> readFromFile(Path file) throws FileNotFoundException {
  try (Scanner input = new Scanner(file)) {
    Tree<String> tree = new Tree<>();
    while(input.hasNext()) {
      tree.insert(input.next());
    }
    return tree;
  }
}
```

Notice that I used [`Path`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Path.html) instead of `File`, the [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) pattern, and I don't suppress the exception, instead the caller (likely the `main` method) should handle the exception properly (likely by reporting the file doesn't exist and exiting). Alternatively adding a catch block like so:

```
catch (IOException e) {
  throw new RuntimeException("Could not open " + file, e);
}
```

would avoid forcing callers to handle the exception.

---

Now that we've cleaned up the `Tree` type, your ordering question is likely simpler to answer. If you intend to order the elements as integers, convert the inputs to Integers, e.g.

```
public static Tree<Integer> readIntsFromFile(Path file) throws FileNotFoundException {
  ...
  tree.insert(Integer.valueOf(input.next()));
  ...
}
```

This will order the tree based on the integer ordering, rather than the strings' lexicographic ordering. This is what I'd suggest you do. It's straightforward and does what you want.

---

If you really want a `Tree<String>` but you want to order them *as if* they were integers you need a custom [`Comparator`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html), as you mention. You would then need to pass the `Comparator` into the `Tree`'s constructor, and call `comparator.compare(element, current.element)` where you currently call `element.compareTo(current.element)`.

Comment: well, that works and all, but if I declare the tree as: Tree<Double> T and then proceed to give as input Double values, then I would ge the    java.lang.NumberFormatException: when I call the insert() method.

Comment: It'd help if you a) clarified which code you're using ("that works" isn't very helpful) as I didn't include a function to process doubles, and b) provided the exact stack trace and error message. If you used `readIntsFromFile()` but swapped `Integer` for `Double` in both the return type and the `insert()` call that should work just fine. Please edit your question with the code you're now using and the stack trace.